# 500 Internal Server Error POST request on Azure using Postman

Tags: azure, http, post, postman

I am trying to send a POST request to Azure's IoTHub using postman. My post url is:

`https://myhubname.azure-devices.net/messages/deviceBound?api-version=2018-06-30`. In my `Params` I have:

`key:` api-version, `value:` 2018-06-30.

In my `Headers` I have:

`key:` Authorization, `value:` "SAS Token"

This is the error I am receiving in the `Body`:

```
  {
    "Message": "ErrorCode:ServerError;InternalServerError",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Tracking ID:0fe2705819fb432383f0a011879cd453-G:2- 
     TimeStamp:12/27/2018 21:07:34"
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be syntax issue, your call is missing device ID.

`https://fully-qualified-iothubname.azure-devices.net/devices/{id}/messages/deviceBound?api-version=2018-06-30`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/device/senddeviceevent

Hope this helps.